# SwayWM: How to create a tabbed container with the mouse?

Tags: swaywm

In SwayWM it's possible to hold mod and drag windows to rearrange them. By default it seems when dragging a window onto the center of another window the positions are swapped.
Instead of that I would like to be able to drag a window onto another to create a tabbed container with both of those windows in it. Is that possible in Sway? And if so, how?

I tried looking in the documentation but couldn't find anything. Mouse support is limited it seems, so perhaps I'll look at a different WM if it's not possible with Sway. I'm only starting my journey of trying out different WMs, coming from Gnome, so I'm definitely open to trying other WMs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle tabbed on the first window. Mod+drag another window to the title bar of the tabbed window to add it to the tabbed container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find documentation about it, but you can $mod+drag to the corner of another window's title bar to tab those windows together, creating a new tabbed container if necessary.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Oh this sounds exactly like what I want! Sadly I have removed Sway since I posted this, buuuut I might give it another try with this knowledge. I'll report back if/when I get to that :P Thank you!